# Css not loading in point_of_sale OpenERP 8

Tags: css, configuration, odoo, point-of-sale

I have a module that is an extension of the point of sale from OpenERP 8, I have properly set the css path in the `__openerp__.py` like this:

`'css': ['static/src/css/mycss.css']`
but with no luck I don't know why but my css is not being loaded like it did not even existed. If you have any ideas that can help me please I would be really grateful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know that in the OpenERP things has changed a little now instead of putting

```
    'css':['static/src/css/mycss.css']
```

you have to use `xpath` to load your css file. [This](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-css-and-js-inheritance-works-on-odoo-v8-55278) link solved my problem